# Eureka form: change TextField color does not work

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I use [Eureka form](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) and want to change text color of the input field.
I tried everything to change text color of `textfield` in a Row of [Eureka form](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) but it does not work.

I tried to change `textColor` and also `attributedText` but nothing happened.

```
<<< IntRow() {
            $0.title = "Title"
            $0.value = 2020
        }.cellSetup({ (cell, row) in
            cell.textLabel?.font  = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
            cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.systemOrange
            cell.textField.textColor = UIColor.red
            cell.textField.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "123", attributes: [
                .foregroundColor: UIColor.red
            ])
```

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that we cannot update the `UITextField` in `cellSetup`. Instead, I have to update the style in `cellUpdate`.

```
.cellUpdate({ (cell, row) in
                cell.textField.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
                cell.textField.textColor = UIColor.systemOrange
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
cell.titleLabel?.textColor = .yourColor
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         cell.textLabel?.textAlignment =  .left
         cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Utils.JFSemiBold1, size: 16)
         cell.textLabel?.textColor   = Utils.isDark() ? .white : .black
         cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Utils.JFCondensed1, size: 16)
```